# PHPUnit error -

Tags: php, apache, phpunit, netbeans-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I was having an issue after installing PEAR on Windows Server 2008 R2 running apache 2.2.21 and PHP5.3. After the installation it said "The 'pear' command is now at your service at c:\php5.3\pear.bat"

```
C:\PHP5.3>pear -V
PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION for php_sqlsrv: entering
PHP_RINIT for php_sqlsrv: entering
sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors = On
sqlsrv.LogSeverity = -1
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems = -1
PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.3.21
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
```

Ok, all good. PHPUnit installed without giving me errors. Then in Netbeans I set up a small class in our MVC framework. Try to run a unit test on it but received this error:

```
'"@php_bin@"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I done a few searches and came across this question on here: [Can't seem to set my php.exe path in pear.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795217/cant-seem-to-set-my-php-exe-path-in-pear-bat)

In the pear.bat and phpunit-skelgen.bat files changed

```
IF "%PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR%"=="" SET "PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR=C:\PHP5.3\pear"
IF "%PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR%"=="" SET "PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR=C:\PHP5.3"
IF "%PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%"=="" SET "PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=C:\PHP5.3\php.exe"
```

to this:

```
SET "PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR=C:\PHP5.3\pear"
SET "PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR=C:\PHP5.3"
SET "PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=C:\PHP5.3\php.exe"
```

Now when I run tests in Netbeans, it gives me this error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

here is what I have tried,

1. Mapped a drive to the server where PHPUnit resides and set the path in Netbeans to the phpunit.bat and phpunit-skelgen.bat
2. Set the files using UNC path.

Still getting the same error. It's not telling me what path is having the issue.

Dev environment:
OS: Win 7 64bit,
Netbeans: 7.2

Server Environment: 
OS: Win server 2008 R2,
PHP 5.3,
Pear: 1.9.4,
apache 2.2.21

Comment: got it to work. I ran this: 
`code`
pear clear-cache pear config-set auto_discover 1; pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit; pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator
`code`

Comment: Had to also change the require path in the phpunit-skelgen file